# SQL Server 2014 : the column was specified multiple times

Tags: sql-server

I am getting the following error when trying to run this query

```
 select  
     Q1.CompanyProductID, Q1.InvoiceMasterID, Q1.TotalAmnt,
     Q2.TotalCommission 
from
    (select CompanyProductID, IM.InvoiceMasterID, A.TotalAmnt, A.InvoiceMasterId 
     from InvoiceMaster IM 
     inner join
         (select invoicemasterid, sum(Amount) as TotalAmnt 
          from invoicepremiumline 
          group by invoicemasterid) A on a.InvoiceMasterId = IM.InvoiceMasterID) as Q1 
inner join
(select im.InvoiceMasterID, im.CompanyProductID, C.TotalCommission 
 from InvoiceMaster im 
 inner join 
     (select InvoiceMasterID, sum(CompanyCommission) as TotalCommission 
      from Commission 
      group by InvoiceMasterID) C on im.InvoiceMasterID = C.InvoiceMasterID) as Q2 on Q2.InvoiceMasterID = Q1.InvoiceMasterID
```

Error:

> The column 'invoicemasterid' was specified multiple times for 'Q1'

Comment: The column names of the Q1 derived table must be unique or aliased to make them unique. For example, you could change `A.InvoiceMasterId` to `A.InvoiceMasterId AS InvoiceMasterId_A` and the references accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message tells you that there are two columns named `invoicemasterid` in the derived table aliased `q1`. Look at `im.invoicemasterid` and `a.invoicemasterid` in the subquery.

Because of the inner join on `im.invoicemasterid = a.invoicemasterid` in the subquery both share an equal value. So you can safely remove one of them from the list of columns in the subquery.